# Shell script for string replacement of HTML file

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sed, terminal

I'm trying to take an HTML template and replace a few placeholders with a custom string.

I'm doing a curl of a template on github: `str=$(curl https://raw.github.com/toneworm/template-html5-sass/master/index.html)` saving the following to a variable:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="[name]">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>[name]</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do a global replace `[name]` with something else (TEST in this example)...

Currently I have `sed -i 's/\[name\]/TEST/g' $first > index.html` which throws the following error:-

```
sed: 1: "<!DOCTYPE": invalid command code <
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for multiple search replace check out 
[this link](http://github.com/vahidhedayati/replace_content)

You can also use Perl which simplifies by not requiring you to backslash content:

```
#RAND=$$;
in1="$1"
out1="$2";
#cp $3 /tmp/$3.$RAND
in=$in1 out=$out1 perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' $3
```

and here is an alternative way of using 1 file:

```
url=https://raw.github.com/toneworm/template-html5-sass/master/index.html; curl $url |sed "s:\[name\]:TEST:g" > index1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$first" | sed -e 's/\[name\]/TEST/g' > index.html
```

Comment: You should double-quote `$first`, or else word splitting and glob expansion may have unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saving the output of the `curl` command to a string variable ? You could save the file to a different name and then use that file for the `sed`.

```
curl https://raw.github.com/toneworm/template-html5-sass/master/index.html test.html
sed "s|\[name\]|TEST|g" test.html > index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Several others have given alternatives that solve the problem; let me explain why the original doesn't work. There are actually three problems:

1. sed's `-i` flag takes an argument (optional in the GNU version of sed, required in the BSD version OS X uses). So `s/\[name\]/TEST/g` gets interpreted as an argument to `-i` instead of an edit operation. BTW, `-i` means operate on an existing file in-place, but since you aren't operating on a file this is unwanted anyway.
2. After the edit to perform, sed's next argument should be a filename to operate on, not a string to operate on. You either need to save it to a file, or `echo` it and pipe that into sed.
3. Since `$first` is not in double-quotes, the shell performs word splitting (and some other things) on it after expansion. This means that "`<!DOCTYPE`", "`html>`", "`<html`" etc are each passed to sed as separate arguments. Since `s/\[name\]/TEST/g` got interpreted as an argument to `-i`, the first one ("`<!DOCTYPE`") gets treated as an edit command (which is invalid), and the rest as filenames (which it never gets around to trying to open).